# How to create a definition for 'module.exports' function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am exporting a function like this which works.

```
module.exports = function (options: any): RequestHandler {
    // Do stuff
}
```

I am trying to add a definition for the exported function, but I am not sure if this is the right way to do it:

```
declare global {
  export function tsm(options: any): RequestHandler
}
```

When I try to test it both of the following say that this is valid:

```
const tsm = require('ts-middleware')

global.tsm() // Gives intellisense
tsm()        // Also gives intellisense
```

It shouldn't give information about `global.tsm()`, so I think that I created my definition wrong. What is the correct way to create a function definition?

I don't want to use the function like this:

```
const tsm = require('ts-middleware')
tsm.tsm()
```

But I do want to use it like this:

```
const tsm = require('ts-middleware')
tsm()
```

Answer (score 0):

To define typings for a module, use `declare module 'x' {...}`. i.e.:

```
declare module 'ts-middleware' {
  export = (option: any): RequestHandler
}
```

However, you do not really need to do that because you wrote your code in TypeScript. The compiler can generate the typings for you automatically.

You just need to add `declaration: true` in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true
  }
}
```

Also, I would strongly recommend you to write your code using ESM. i.e. instead of `module.exports = ...`:

```
// named export, preferred
export function foo(options: any): RequestHandler { ... }

// or default export
export default function foo(options: any): RequestHandler { ... }

// import in TypeScript for named export
import { foo } from 'ts-middleware'

// import in TypeScript for default export
import foo from 'ts-middleware'

// require in JavaScript commonjs
const middleware = require('ts-middleware')
middleware.foo(...)
```